# MS-Word paragraph mark (¶) shows in equation mode, how to change normal mode

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-word

I have did MS-Word automation to convert OOML (Word-Equation) to MathML, but some cases word paragraph symbol (¶) shows in equation mode.
My question is how to do automation, to change those symbol into normal mode using VSTO/VBA.

Answer (score 0):

To hide paragraph symbols you could trigger the following line of code (VBA):

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
```

However, I am not sure if this solves your problem as you could see the symbol as a part of your equation (it would not be paragraph ending mark but just a symbol). To remove it in such situation you could just try to use `Replace function`:

```
Replace("your string here with ¶", Chr(182), "")
```

where **Chr(182) == ¶**.